# Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'fooMadeBy' does not exist in type 'WritableDraft<MyType>'

Tags: typescript, redux, types, react-redux

I'm new to redux and ts and I got into this project where they want me to pass the `fooMadeBy`, among other properties, to the state. Most of there were quite simple,  but for some reason this one gives me error and I don't really understand why and there is not a lot of info about it.

Here is my code :

```
export const FooSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'foo',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fooLoadSuccess: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<fooResponseDto>
    ) => {
      const { foos } = action.payload;
      state.getFooStatus = FetchStatus.SUCCEEDED;
      const foo = foos[0];
      state.foo = foo
        ? {
          // other properties
          fooMadeBy: foo.fooMadeBy,
        }
        : undefined;
    },

    resetState: () => initialState,
  },
});
```

Error:

```
Type '{ fooId: string; comment: string; fooStatus: FooStatus; fooMadeAt: string; fooMadeBy: string; ... 4 more ...; reviewerFoo: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'WritableDraft<Foo>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'fooMadeBy' does not exist in type 'WritableDraft<Foo>'. Did you mean to write 'fooMadeAt'?
```

I already added the property type to Foo types, but still giving me that `WritableDraft` error and can't figure out why.

Thanks

Comment: maybe its just a typo? *Did you mean to write 'fooMadeAt'?*

Comment: Without knowing what the initialState is and what types you are using here this is impossible to answer

Comment: Is not a typo, I meant fooMadeBy. initial state is ```const initialState: IFooState = {
  foo: undefined,
};```
And IFooState is: 
```export type IFooState = {
  isFooAmmended?: boolean;
  foo: Foo | undefined;
  saveFooStatus?: FetchStatus;
  getFooStatus?: FetchStatus;
};```

I can keep going up the ladder and tell you all the types, Foo type has fooMadeBy